# how can i convert my object into array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

my data looks like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57ef642fd4f27bb41b697314"),
    "compCode": "0001",
    "menuName": "Cash",
    "menuDesc": "Cash Module",
    "formName": "",
    "search": "n",
    "effStatus": "A",
    "dispSeq": "20",
    "subMenu1": [{
        "menuName": "Cash Vouchers",
        "menuDesc": "Vouchers",
        "formName": "",
        "search": "n",
        "effStatus": "A",
        "dispSeq": "10",
        "subMenu2": {
            "menuName": "Cash Voucher",
            "menuDesc": "Maintain Cash Voucher",
            "formName": "cavoucher",
            "search": "n",
            "effStatus": "A",
            "dispSeq": "10"
        }
    }]
};
```

i have given my data above this result i have achieve this result using mongodb aggregate query but i want my submenu2 must be in array  not as object is this possible when i tried to group subMenu2 by doing this  "subMenu1.subMenu2": { "$addToSet": "$subMenu1" } it shows me an error can't use . in group statement so how can i do that my expected result is

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57ef642fd4f27bb41b697314"),
    "compCode": "0001",
    "menuName": "Cash",
    "menuDesc": "Cash Module",
    "formName": "",
    "search": "n",
    "effStatus": "A",
    "dispSeq": "20",
    "subMenu1": [{
        "menuName": "Cash Vouchers",
        "menuDesc": "Vouchers",
        "formName": "",
        "search": "n",
        "effStatus": "A",
        "dispSeq": "10",
        "subMenu2": [{
            "menuName": "Cash Voucher",
            "menuDesc": "Maintain Cash Voucher",
            "formName": "cavoucher",
            "search": "n",
            "effStatus": "A",
            "dispSeq": "10"
        }]
    }]
};
```

and my aggregate query

```
db.sys_mainmenu.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$subMenu1"}, 
    {$unwind:"$subMenu1.subMenu2"},
    {$match:{"subMenu1.subMenu2.formName":{"$in":"cavoucher","systranslate"]}}},
 { "$group": { 

                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "compCode":{"$first":"$compCode"},
                     "menuName":{"$first":"$menuName"}, 
                    "menuDesc": {"$first":"$menuDesc"}, 
                    "formName": {"$first":"$formName"}, 
                    "search": {"$first":"$search"}, 
                    "effStatus":{"$first": "$effStatus"}, 
                    "dispSeq": {"$first":"$dispSeq"},
                    "subMenu1": { "$addToSet": "$subMenu1" }

                }
    }
```

])

Comment: Can you show your aggregation query?

Comment: db.sys_mainmenu.aggregate([{$unwind:"$subMenu1"},$unwind:"$subMenu1.subMenu2"},{$match:{"subMenu1.subMenu2.formName":{"$in":["cavoucher","systranslate"]}}},{ "$group": {                     
                        "_id": "$_id","subMenu1": { "$addToSet": "$subMenu1" }         
                    }
        }
 ])